# Docker CentOS 7 cannot write to /var/logs/

Tags: docker, centos, elastic-stack, selinux

I am trying to create an ELK container on CentOS which runs fine, however, no logs are created and I dunno why, my guess it is because of the SELinux, however, the Docker log is empty (nothing which suggests this).

I am mounting the directory as follows:

```
/var/logs:/var/logs:Z
```

What I am doing wrong? Please help

Comment: Show your Dockerfile, and your `docker run` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have resolved this issue by passing --privileged argument at the runtime of the container

Comment: It is a really bad idea to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SELinux enabled, then it must be reason you cannot write into that folder.

Check your /var/log/audit/audit.log for SELinux logs.

For instance, you could execute the following command in order to get reports about SELinux denies:

> sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log

It will tell you what to do to allow any missing privileges.